# How to implement a lazy getObject method like Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, design-patterns

I have a very large XML file from a legacy software. Its size is something about 9 GB.

I need to get parts of this XML in a lazy way, just like Hibernate does with databases. I already have POJOs in hierarchical structure to represent the records inside the XML and want to retrieve data from XML from POJO's 'get' methods since I have the Root element. Of course I can create a Manager class or sort of, but I want the same as the Hibernate does with lazy load.

Is there any pattern or library that could be used to change the behavior of a class method, exactly as Lazy Load in Hibernate?

Comment: You can use proxy pattern to achieve this, return a proxy instance and call actual method when really required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your motivation is that huge amount of data. I don't know of any such library and I imagine this as a difficult task, as XML is very hard to point to the needed fragments.

The best I can imagine is event based processing (e.g. [SAX](http://www.saxproject.org/)) and transform it into an appropriate database scheme. The rest is ordinary JPA (e.g. hibernate) mapping.

Comment: The time to insert all data into database tables should take too much time and storage (there is 1 XML file per day). But I agree, it's an option that I'm considering.

Comment: You could omit the transformation step and work directly event based with the XML file without your POJOs.